# Low CPU Utilization of GCP

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, svm, cpu

On the Google Cloud Platform (GCP), I have the following specs:

- Machine type: n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory)
- CPU platform: Intel Haswell

I am using Jupyter notebook to fit an SVM to large amounts of NLP data. This process is very slow, and according to the GCP I am only utilizing around [0.12% of CPUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZXjy.png)

How do I increase CPU utilization?

Comment: Actually, you're using 12% (12/100). This corresponds to one vCPU. This is because -- IIRC -- Jupyter is a Python app and Python's single-threaded so you're stuck using one core. You could reduce the number of cores (the OS will use multiple cores, of course) to save yourself some money but you'll need to evaluate alternatives to use more cores.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DazWilkin mentioned actually, you're using 12% (12/100). This corresponds to one vCPU. This is because -- IIRC -- Jupyter is a Python app and Python's single-threaded so you're stuck using one core. You could reduce the number of cores (the OS will use multiple cores, of course) to save yourself some money but you'll need to evaluate alternatives to use more cores.